# pass color from view to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi guys i have a view where i have some tags and that tags has a color, i cant change that color via css directly cause its a pseudo element `.tag::after what i need is pass that value`@tag.color` to the script but i have no idea how to do it i know that when i already did it i can change it easy with the hover and the css change via jquery but how can i pass the value?

```
 @foreach (var tags in i.Tags)
             {
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <ul class="tagMargin">
                        <li><a href="#" class="tag" style="background-color:@tags.cor;color:black;font-size:9px">@tags.NomeTag</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
             }
```

Comment: I can't understand what do you want exactly. Explane more

Comment: i want to change the hover color on an element i have the color that i want in my Model how can i pass it to jquery or css?

Comment: in css do li.tag:hover. But you're already in a tag for loop, lose the excess @tags and format your style correctly.

Comment: but that @tag.color come from databas i need to format the color with that color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JQuery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements

Having recreated a simple controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var sampleList = new List<SampleModel>();
    sampleList.Add(new SampleModel
    {
        Color = "#2ecc71",
        Name = "Emerald"
    });
    sampleList.Add(new SampleModel
    {
        Color = "#2980b9",
        Name = "Belize Hole"
    });
    sampleList.Add(new SampleModel
    {
        Color = "#c0392b",
        Name = "Pomegranate"
    });


    return View(sampleList.ToList());
}
```

And the view with my data attribute

```
@foreach(var tags in Model)
{
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="tag" style="background-color:@tags.Color;color:black;font-size:9px" data-color="@tags.Color">@tags.Name</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

Simply retrieve the values of the attribute using JQuery by looping through the list items with the class `.tag`

```
var array = [];

$('.tag').each(function () {
    array.push($(this).data('color'));
})
console.log(array);
```

Results:

```
["#2ecc71", "#2980b9", "#c0392b"]
```